# How to reset folder ownership in Windows 10

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-10, file-permissions

Having had trouble writing to a root directory as a particular user, I opted to change the directory ownership to that particular user on Windows 10 under;

```
    Folder Properties / Security / Advanced
     Owner (Change) > Include all sub-folders and inheritables
```

Since this account was the only one I use on my PC (and not knowing better) I decided to do the same for the entire drive, and although I encountered problems with some files, it generally worked. There were however consequences that caused other Windows processes, such as MS Edge, to slow significantly when opening a new window or modifying settings.

Is there a way to revert all folders to their original/default owners?

Note that 
[WINDOWS: Taking Back/Restoring Default Ownership Permissions of directory](https://superuser.com/questions/736064/windows-taking-back-restoring-default-ownership-permissions-of-directory)
relates only to a single directory, not the full system.

Comment: I hope windows sfc could fix it.

Comment: @RogUE what do you mean? I'm way out of my depth here - anything is more than I've got right now.

Comment: @RogUE do you have a current link? The one you posted appears to be out of date or incorrect.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/929833

Comment: Close, but no cigar. Noticeable improvements with the start menu, but MS Edge is still painfully slow - the supposed root has also been untouched, no change to file ownership.